# What is proper syntax for returning a string with MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-insert

I followed the example provided in our class material and made a function that returns a count. Now I am trying to make a function that would get me the full name of a user by the same principle I made the count function but I keep getting this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

```
CREATE FUNCTION getAuthorFullName (authorID INT)
RETURNS CHAR(45)
BEGIN
DECLARE author CHAR(45);
SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ',last) FROM person as fullName
JOIN user ON user.idPerson = fullName.idPerson
WHERE idUser LIKE authorID
INTO author;
RETURN author;
```

I checked the SELECT query on its own and it retrieves the correct full name of the author when I pass the authors ID manually so I just have to get it working in a function where I can simply pass the author's ID.

Comment: Did you change the DELIMITER?

Answer (score 1):

`INTO` go after the value.

Also if idUser is integer use `=` operator. `LIKE` id for strings

```
SELECT CONCAT(first, ' ',last) INTO author
FROM person as fullName
JOIN user ON user.idPerson = fullName.idPerson
WHERE idUser = authorID
;
```

Here is a **[sql demo](https://rextester.com/MMS37028)**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getAuthorFullName;

CREATE FUNCTION getAuthorFullName (authorID INT)
RETURNS CHAR(45)
BEGIN
DECLARE author CHAR(45) ;
SELECT CONCAT('first', ' ','last' ) INTO author;
RETURN author;
END;

SELECT getAuthorFullName(1);
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html says "MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT standard SQL syntax"

Comment: @ADyson `select .. into..` is a different beast. You are mixing two different things here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: However, one problem with the solution is that `SELECT..INTO` specifically requires the query to return **1** row only. Otherwise it throws error; without any idea of table data from OP, a `LIMIT 1` is required at the end for the query to perform without any errors.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya didn't know that, thanks. I see the difference - selecting into a variable (supported) vs selecting into a table (not supported). And of course this is the former case.

Comment: @ADyson yes those are two different things

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I hope the    `WHERE idUser = authorID` is enough to restrict to a single result.